# MVVM and View/ViewModel hierarchy

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, mvvm, viewmodel

I'm working on making my first game using C# and XAML for Windows 8. I'm still learning the core concepts and best practices, and MVVM has been a hurdle. I'll attempt to ask the question in two parts.

**Background**

The game I'm making is Sudoku. Sudoku has a board that contains a 9x9 grid of tiles. I have three models - `Game`, `Board`, and `Tile`. When a `Game` is created, it automatically creates a `Board`, and when the `Board` is created, it creates 81 (9x9) `Tiles`.

**1. With a hierarchy of views, how are corresponding view models created?**

To match the hierarchy of models, I would like to have a hierarchy of views (`GameView` contains a `BoardView` which contains 81 `TileViews`). In XAML, it's pretty easy to create this hierarchy of views with user controls, but I don't understand how the view models get created.

In the examples I've seen, the data context of a user control is often set to the view model (using the `ViewModelLocator` as a source) which creates a fresh instance of the view model. This seems to work well if you have a flat view, but also seems like it gets messy when you have a hierarchy. Does the `GameView` create a `GameViewModel` and leave it up to its `BoardView` child to create a `BoardViewModel`? If so, how does the `GameViewModel` communicate with the `BoardViewModel`? Can the `BoardViewModel` communicate back up the hierarchy to the `GameViewModel`?

**2. How does a view model get model data?**

In iOS, I would start by using a service to fetch a `Game` model that was pre-populated with data. I would then create a `GameViewController` view controller (which was in charge of creating the view) and pass the `Game` to it. In MVVM, I see the value in having a view be in charge of creating its own view model (ideally using a `ViewModelLocator`), but I don't understand how that view model gets the model.

In all of the examples I've found online, the view model uses some service to fetch its own data. But I haven't come across any example that accepts constructor params or params passed from a higher level of navigation. How is this done?

I don't want to use an application resource or some other kind of singleton storage method for my model because, not that I do, but what if I wanted to display multiple puzzles on the screen at once? Each `GameView` should contain its own `Game`.

Not only does the `GameViewModel` need a reference to the `Game` model, but the `BoardViewModel` that was created somehow (see question 1) needs a reference to the `Board` model that belongs to the `Game` model. The same goes for all the `Tiles`. How is all this information passed down the chain? Can I do this much heavy lifting entirely within XAML, or am I going to have to do some sort of binding or other initialization in code?

*Phew!*

I appreciate any advice you can give, even if it's not a full answer. I'm also keen to find any examples of MVVM projects that share similar challenges to my own. Thanks a ton!

Comment: I think you are talking about the nested user controls problem (see http://catel.catenalogic.com/index.htm?gs_viewscontrols_nested_user_controls_problem.htm).

Catel itself is not available for WinRT yet (a beta  is though), but you can at least understand how I think it should be done.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I would start by creating a class to begin the application with. Typically I call that class something like `ApplicationViewModel` or `ShellViewModel`, even though technically it can abide by different rules than what I would typically use for a `ViewModel`

This class gets instantiated at startup, and is the `DataContext` for the `ShellView` or `ApplicationView`

```
// App.xaml.cs
private void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    var shellVM = new ShellViewModel(); 
    var shellView = new ShellView();    
    shellView.DataContext = shellVM;  
    shellView.Show(); 
}
```

This is usually the only place I set a `DataContext` for a UI component directly. From this point on, **your ViewModels are the application**. Its important to keep this in mind when working with MVVM. Your Views are simply a user friendly interface that allows users to interact with the ViewModels. They're not actually considered part of the application code.

For example, your `ShellViewModel` may contain:

- `BoardViewModel CurrentBoard`
- `UserViewModel CurrentUser`
- `ICommand NewGameCommand`
- `ICommand ExitCommand`

and your `ShellView` might contain something like this:

```
<DockPanel>
    <Button Command="{Binding NewGameCommand}" 
            Content="New Game" DockPanel.Dock="Top" />
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentBoard}" />
</DockPanel>
```

This will actually render your `BoardViewModel` object into the UI as the `ContentControl.Content`. To specify how to draw your `BoardViewModel`, you can either specify a `DataTemplate` in `ContentControl.ContentTemplate`, or use implicit `DataTemplates`.

An implicit DataTemplate is simply a `DataTemplate` for a class that doesn't have an `x:Key` associated with it. WPF will use this template anytime it encounters an object of the specified class in the UI.

So using

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:BoardViewModel}">
        <local:BoardView />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

will mean that instead of drawing

```
<ContentControl>
    BoardViewModel
</ContentControl>
```

it will draw

```
<ContentControl>
    <local:BoardView />
</ContentControl>
```

Now the `BoardView` could contain something like

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Squares}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="3" Columns="3" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

and it would draw a board using a 3x3 `UniformGrid`, with each cell containing the contents of your `Squares` array. If your `BoardViewModel.Squares` property happened to be an array of `TileModel` objects, then each grid cell would contain a `TileModel`, and you could again use an implicit `DataTemplate` to tell WPF how to draw each `TileModel`

Now as for how your `ViewModel` gets its actual data objects, that's up to you. I prefer to abstract all data access behind a class such as a `Repository`, and have my `ViewModel` simply call something like `SodokuRepository.GetSavedGame(gameId);`. It makes the application easy to test and maintain.

However you get your data, keep in mind that the `ViewModel` and `Models` are your application, so they should be responsible for getting data. Don't do that in the `View`. Personally I like keeping my `Model` layer for plain objects that hold data only, so only ever perform data access operations from my ViewModels.

For communication between `ViewModels`, I actually have an [article on my blog](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/06/05/communication-between-viewmodels-with-mvvm/) about that. To summarize, use a messaging system such as Microsoft Prism's `EventAggregator` or MVVM Light's `Messenger`. They work like a kind of paging system: any class can subscribe to receive messages of a specific type, and any class can broadcast messages.

For example, your `ShellViewModel` might subscribe to receive `ExitProgram` messages and close the application when it hears one, and you can broadcast an `ExitProgram` message from anywhere in your application.

I suppose another method would be to just attach handlers from one class to another, such as calling `CurrentBoardViewModel.ExitCommand += Exit;` from the `ShellViewModel`, but I find that messy and prefer using a messaging system.

Anyways, I hope that answers some of your questions and will point you in the right direction. Goodluck with your project :)

Comment: Wow, that's a lot to digest! Let me summarize to see if I've got it: Parent views will contain ContentTemplates with the content attribute set to view model objects. DataTemplates define those ContentTemplates to contain the corresponding views. This means you're not using a ViewModelLocator or IoC, correct?

Comment: Also, the data access still concerns me. If the view model is responsible for fetching its own model, is there a way I can specify additional information about which model to use? If I have hard puzzles and easy puzzles, how do I tell my new GameViewModel which puzzle to use?

Comment: @BrentTraut Personally I don't like using the ViewModelLocator. There are some restrictions with it, such as you can only have one instance of your ViewModel, and not being able to pass it parameters. I prefer to build my application in code, and have the UI simply provide a user-friendly interface for my classes.

Comment: @BrentTraut As for your question about data access, that kind of logic I would put in the ViewModel. Either the user selects a puzzle to load (in which case, you'd have an `ObservableCollection<GameBoard> AvailablePuzzles` and `GameBoard SelectedPuzzle` in your `ViewModel`) or you load one based on some other logic in your `ViewModel`

Comment: @Rachel You choose to build your visual hierarchy in XAML by specifying ViewModels and having DataTemplates replace them with the corresponding View objects (instead of specifying the Views directly and having a ViewModelLocator or another approach at binding the ViewModels). This approach seems to make it more difficult to fine tune the visual layout when multiple views exist in the same window. For example, if you have two views bound to ViewModels of the same class in one window, then using your approach it would be difficult alter one's size without affecting the other.

Comment: @Roman I'm not too sure I understand what you mean. The idea behind it is to have your Views totally separate from your ViewModels. I've always found it very easy to manipulate and maintain the UI layer using this method, as it's completely independent of the data layer.